# Refresh .profile and .bashrc

Tags: path, bashrc

I've split up my `.profile` and `.bashrc` files like so based on various advice I've read. I have an alias `bin` which I use to refresh my  environment after changing `.profile` and `.bashrc` to avoid exiting and re-opening the shell. However, there are two problems currently:

1. My `$PATH` will grow for each refresh because I prepend the default `$PATH`.
2. I only want `fortune` when I start a new shell, not when refreshing it with `bin`.

What is the most correct, non-hackish way to refresh my environment without the unwanted side-effects? (Copy-pasting the system path into my `.profile` is *not* an option!)

**`.profile`**

```
# LOTS OF EXPORTS
export ***
export ***
export PATH=.:$HOME/bin:***:$PATH

shopt -s extglob
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fortune
```

**`.bashrc`**

```
# LOTS OF ALIASES
alias ***
alias ***
alias bin='source $HOME/.profile; set +h'

# LOTS OF FUNCTIONS
foo() {}
bar() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most non-hackish way to refresh the environment is to quit the current shell session and start a new one.

---

You may also start a new login shell from the current shell, but that may have unwanted consequences, such as modifying `PATH` even though you've already modified your `PATH` (environment variables are inherited by the new shell, and not reset to what they would have been if you had started a new shell in a new terminal).

You could also start a new shell with `env -i bash -l`, where `env -i` would clear the environment before invoking a new `bash` login shell.  This may not be the same as starting a new shell in a new terminal either, as the inherited environment would not be the same.

Comment: The first suggestion says `/bin/fortune: No such file` even though `fortune` is in `/usr/local/bin`, which is in my `PATH`. Also no aliases are set. The second gives me an almost empty `env` (only `PWD` & `SHLVL` are set), but all my aliases seem to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an inline test and export your path conditionally in `.bashrc`

```
[[ $PATH =~ "$HOME/bin" ]] && export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

As for the `fortune` command, you can have it run on login by adding it in `.bash_profile` which is executed by only login shells. You can force your Terminal emulator to start a Login shell in the app's preferences.

Comment: The `.profile` file is used if `.bash_profile` does not exist, so your comment about this file is not needed. Also, inserting guards in the files is a bit hackish...